# Radio button is checked but value of ng-model is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So basically a restaurant has two attributes dine_in or home_delivery. If both of them are true, then I let the user decide which he/she wants to use. But if only dine_in or only home_delivery is available at I would show them only the corresponding radio button and they need not click on radio button again.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="row-fluid" style="line-height: 30px;">
    Location: 
    <input type="radio" id="r1" ng-show= "outlet.attributes.dine_in == true" ng-model="checkin.location" value="DINE_IN" ng-checked="outlet.attributes.dine_in == true && outlet.attributes.home_delivery == false"> 
    <label for="r1" ng-show= "outlet.attributes.dine_in == true"> Dine-In</label> 
    <input type="radio" id="r2" ng-model="checkin.location" ng-show= "outlet.attributes.home_delivery == true" value="HOME_DELIVERY" ng-change="checkin_select_dirty = false" ng-checked="outlet.attributes.dine_in == false && outlet.attributes.home_delivery == true"> 
    <label for="r2" ng-show= "outlet.attributes.home_delivery == true"> Home Delivery / Take-away</label>
</div>
```

Here my problem is although Home-Delivery or Dine-In button is shown as checked but value of ng-model `checkin.location` is undefined. Only when I click on the radio button again, ng-model is passed corresponding value. `checkin_select_dirty` is for the case when both options are available and user hasn't checked any one of them. It is used to prompt user to select one of them.

Comment: did you give the model properties initial values in the controller?

Comment: No. I thought ng-model would be automatically given the value if option button is checked.